# how to uninstall openCV on mac 10.6.8?

Tags: opencv, osx-snow-leopard

I have multiple versions of openCV (2.0,2.1) on my mac. Is there a way to erase these multiple versions and all its files so that i can make a fresh install of openCV 2.3.0

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious command

```
sudo port uninstall opencv
```

may not work, at least in my case it complained that it needs a particular version. I run then

```
sudo port uninstall opencv 4.2
```

All opencv libraries in /opt/local/lib were gone after that command. After that I re-installed openCV with

```
sudo port install opencv
```

(If there is a problem with ffmpeg just uninstlal it with sudo port uninstall ffmpeg)

Reinstalling opencv, by the way, fixed my problems with compilation and linking that I had after switching from Mountain Lion to Maverick (10.9.2). In particular, I had a linker problem in Eclipse:

```
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/opt/local/lib -o "deltetit"  ./src/deltetit.o   -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::imshow(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)", referenced from:
      _main in deltetit.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [deltetit] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the install folder.

And make sure to point to the correct install path when compiling your proj