# Error when using imshow on OS X

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opencv, llvm

I have setup `OpenCV2` in XCode but unfortunately `imshow` does not work:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::imshow(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am running OS X 10.8.4 with latest XCode.

I have attached a few images below to show the setup in XCode and the libraries.
So far it seems that other functions work fine with OpenCV, except this.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: I solved this problem with reinstalling opencv, see this [post][1]:



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22955769/457687

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say that you compiled `OpenCV2` with `libstdc++`, and are now compiling your application with `libc++` support.

You need to compile OpenCV2 with the same `C++` library, otherwise it will not be able to link.

if you do an `nm` of the OpenCV2 library, if it was compiled with `libstdc++`, it will look like:

```
cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)
```

while if it was compiled with `libc++`, it would look like:

```
cv::imshow(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)
```

to get the demangled symbol do:

```
nm library | c++filt | grep cv::imshow
```

Comment: Unfortunately i think you are right. This will kill my initialization of `std::vector` which is quite unfortunate.. `No matching constructor for initialization of 'std::vector<Point32>'`

Comment: Unfortunately, you *have* to compile everything using the same c++ standard library, otherwise insanity could occur at run-time. The namespaces have been doctored to prevent you accidentally doing this (note the `::__1::` in the libc++ compiled option).