# building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, g++

I wrote a code using c++ and OpenCV:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

then I trying to Running my code on the terminal and build using g++:

```
g++ $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv) -std=c++11  yourFile.cpp -o yourFileProgram
```

but I get this error:

```
...
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/opencv/4.5.1_2/lib/libopencv_core.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/opencv/4.5.1_2/lib/libopencv_photo.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::Mat::Mat()", referenced from:
      _main in cv_test-ff1014.o
  "cv::Mat::~Mat()", referenced from:
      _main in cv_test-ff1014.o
  "cv::Mat::operator=(cv::Mat&&)", referenced from:
      _main in cv_test-ff1014.o
  "cv::imread(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in cv_test-ff1014.o
  "cv::imwrite(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > const&)", referenced from:
      _main in cv_test-ff1014.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running OpenCV 3 in Mac Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927294/running-opencv-3-in-mac-terminal)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem, and the short answer is that Apple switched to using `libc++` instead of `libstdc++`. If you want to compile it as you mention (via console g++) then [the answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119445/error-when-using-imshow-on-os-x).

Also, you have mention `g++` in tag, but be sure that [you understand that gcc is alias of clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40034457/os-x-installed-gcc-links-to-clang), and for using `g++` compiler you have to print `g++-10`.

Way to compile `OpenCV` whith `g++` via terminal as you provide in the example is [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927294/running-opencv-3-in-mac-terminal?rq=1)

The best way to include `OpenCV` lib on macOS is to install via homebrew opencv lib, and just generate `CMakeLists.txt`. Possible example for it:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(PROJECT_NAME)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

#set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/local/bin/g++-10" CACHE STRING "C++ compiler" FORCE)
#set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/local/bin/gcc-10" CACHE STRING "C compiler" FORCE)

add_executable(PROJECT_NAME main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(PROJECT_NAME ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Note, that if you will force to use `g++-10` (uncomment set structure) then there will be [problem like described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23503551/opencv-compile-with-clang-ok-with-gcc-not-ok-os-x-10-9).
I think there is no `OpenCV` update for `arm`, then just ignore the warning and try something like that.

Comment: I want to use g++

Comment: @SajjadAemmi `g++` is alias of `clang` on macOS. If you mean `g++ compiler` then I have already mention how to you it in the answer to another question