# Xcode gcc: dependency_info.dat No such file or directory

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, gcc, g++

Hi anyone can help with `dependency_info.dat No such file or directory`? I'm using Xcode 7 with gcc 4.8

```
-dependency_info /path/my_project/build/my_project/Debug/my_project.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/my_project_dependency_info.dat

g++-4.8: error:/path/my_project/build/my_project/Debug/my_project.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/my_project_dependency_info.dat: No such file or directory
Command /usr/local/bin/g++-4.8 failed with exit code 1
```

what does `-dependency_info` flag do? How can I remove this flag?

Answer (score 0):

The error went away after I deleted the path specified in Build Settings "Path to Linker Dependency Info File" for the project and the targets.  So far the app is compiling and running fine without a specified path.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 7.2, and there is no such property in Build Settings pane (or I couldn't find it for hours, and it's likely. because I'm rather new to Xcode) Can you be a little bit more specific please? Where to find this setting? Thanks

Comment: I'm on Xcode7.1 now and I'm not finding it there.  I still see it in Xcode6.4.  I don't know much about this setting.  It may have been created by a predecessor on the project.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar error with Xcode 7.2, OpenCV 3 and El Capitan.

In my case (and probably in yours as well), it's a linker error disguised as something else.

My project builds fine via terminal (because it already has a makefile that uses gcc), but no chance with XCode even after I configure everything in Build Settings pane according to the makefile.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19119996/87359) saved me. My OpenCV was installed using macports (it might have been precompiled binaries, or compiled on my machine, can't remember). It turns out that it's compiled with **libc++** and not **libstdc++**.

Changing the *C++ Standard Library* setting accordingly in Build Settings did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was trying to use a "/" in the app's display name that caused the build error